# Enable Core Dumps for crashed process in macOS Sierra

Tags: coredump, macos-sierra, ulimit, sysctl

I need to enable Core Dump File creation for processes which terminated by SIGABRT,SIGBUS, etс..

In previous versions of MAC OS X (include ElCapitan) to enable Code Dumps file for all processes i'm will do:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.corefile=/Users/tester/core.%U.%P.%N.dump
sudo sysctl -w kern.coredump=1
sudo launchctl limit core unlimited
sudo ulimit -c unlimited
launchctl limit core unlimited
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Now thise way does not work.
In [this Site](http://ohmygoditsburning.com/new-stuff-in-macos-sierra/) talk  about new **gcore** command, but it work for running processes.
For KernelCoreDumps now you must enable NVRAM variable [official](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT206871).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `ulimit -c unlimited` with Xcode 9, followed by executing something sure to get a segfault, and, bingo, got a coredump written in `/core/`.
Namely, I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a[2];
printf("\n hi\n");
a[20000]=10;
return 0;
}
```

Save this to a file, say `x.c`, then in the same terminal session where you executed `ulimit` above do `cc x.c` (assuming you have Xcode's command line tools installed), followed by `./a.out`

The coredump was over 700Mb in size, believe it or not.